# Google Analytics filter to include traffic based on subdomain and request URI

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to set up what I believe may be an Advanced Filter.

I want to include all traffic to the m.mydomainname.com subdomain AND also include all traffic to the page mydomainname.com/my_page.html (note that it is on my main domain, not my subdomain).

I can't just do 2 include filters, because if I include all traffic to m.mydomainname.com then that will throw out the hits to mydomainname.com/my_page.html.

Does anyone know the filters I'd need to set up to create a profile which includes all traffic to a subdomain as well as traffic to 1 specific page on my primary domain?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two custom filters:

1. The first filter is used to combine the Hostname and URI into a Custom Field
2. The second filter uses a regular expression, trying to match m.mydomainname.com or mydomainname.com/my_page.html against the Custom Field defined in the first filter.

For the first filter, something like:

```
Custom filter
Advanced
Field A -> Extract A: Hostname, (.*)
Field B -> Extract B: Request URI, (.*)
Output To -> Constructor: Custom Field 1, $A1$B1
```

For the second filter, something like:

```
Custom filter
Include
Filter Field: Custom Field 1
Filter Pattern: m\.mydomainname\.com|mydomainname\.com/my_page\.html
```

The second filter includes all traffic or m.mydomainname.com OR the single page mydomainname.com/mypage.html

---

When working with filters, it's a "best practice" to use two profiles:

- one profile with no filters, that collects all data
- one profile using the filter(s).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just wanted to clarify a couple things... Will the second filter you've provided track traffic to all pages at m.mydomainname.com or just that page?  And second, I missed this in my original question but the second page I'd like to include is actually on a different domain (I'm not worry about cross-domain tracking at this point)... Can I exclude the domain name in the second filter and just put my_page.html or do I have to also include mydomainname.com again?  Thanks so much.

Comment: It should track all traffic on m.mydomainname.com, and just the single page on mydomainname.com. For the single page, I'd include the domain again just to be sure.

Comment: I gave it a shot but now it's not including any traffic

Comment: I also have a filter to display the full host name in the reports as outlined here under "Display Subdomains in the Main Profile" http://www.ericmobley.net/guide-to-tracking-multiple-subdomains-in-google-analytics/.  Perhaps that is causing trouble?  What order should the filters be in?

Comment: That would definitely affect things, since the "Display Subdomains" filter replaces the Request URI fields so it includes the hostname. That's kind-of what the first filter described above was for, except that it output to a custom field.  Try changing the second custom filter above to: Filter Field: Request URI, Filter Pattern: /m\.mydomainname\.com|/mydomainname\.com/my_page\.html